# MS SQL Server Management Studio export to CSV introduces extra character when reading from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ssms

I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio and I have a simple table with the following data:

```
CountryId     CommonName  FormalName
---------     ----------  ----------
        1    Afghanistan  Islamic State of Afghanistan
        2        Albania  Republic of Albania
        3        Algeria  People's Democratic Republic of Algeria
        4        Andorra  Principality of Andorra
```

I use "Save Results As" to save this data into `countries.csv` using the default UTF8 encoding. Then I go into iPython and read it into a data frame using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv("countries.csv")
```

If I do

```
df.columns
```

I get:

```
Index([u'CountryId', u'CommonName', u'FormalName'], dtype='object')
```

The weird thing is that when I copy the column names, paste it into a new cell, and press Enter, I get:

```
u'\ufeffCountryId', u'CommonName', u'FormalName'
```

An unicode character `\ufeff` shows up in the beginning of the first column name.

I tried the procedure with different tables and every time I got the extra character.  And it happens to the first column name only.

Can anyone explain to me why the extra unicode character showed up?

Comment: That is the utf-16 BE BOM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16

Comment: When you copy and paste it looks like there is some silent conversion from utf-8 to utf-16 BE happening

Comment: How are you copying the column names?

Comment: @EdChum just highlight & copy

Comment: From what app is what I meant as you are going to copy into the clip board the data from MS SQL, a text editor, python console etc.. from what app did you do this, also can you post data and steps to reproduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `encoding = "utf-8-sig"` option with `read_csv`. For example:

```
df = pd.read_csv("countries.csv", encoding = "utf-8-sig")
```

That should get it to ignore the Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM) at the start of the CSV file. The use of BOM unnecessary here as UTF-8 files don't have an byte order, but Microsoft tools like to use it as a magic number to identify UTF-8 encoded text files.